# ReactNative: Using React Native Navigation how can I move to next screen

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have root screen that contains 4 bottoms tabs implemented using react-native-navigation, for one of my bottomtab having sub tabs(topTabs) so now how can I navigate to next screen from the current screen.(note: the next screen is not a registered screen in root)

please anyone help me

here is my root navigation

```js
 export const startNavigation = () => {
  Navigation.setRoot({
     root: {
      sideMenu: {
        left: {
          component: {
           name: screenName.DRAWER
       }
        },
         center: {
           bottomTabs: {
             children: [{
              stack: {
                 children: [{
                   component: {
                     name: screenName.Sample1
                   }
                }],
                 options: {
                   bottomTab: {
                     text: 'Sample1',
                   }
                 }
              }
             }, {
               stack: {
                 children: [{
                  component: {
                     name: screenName.HOME
                   }
                 }],
                options: {
                   bottomTab: {
                     text: 'Home',
                     selectedTextColor: 'red'
                   }
                 }
              }
            }],
             options: {
               bottomTabs: {
                 currentTabIndex: 1
               }
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   })
 }
```

from this root, how I will navigate to sub tabs or sunscreens

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried anything? can you post some code?

if you are getting started, here is the official documentation from React Native

https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/Usage

Comment: I'm using react-native-navigation library

Comment: have you gone through the docs, tried something? getting any error?

Comment: I have updated the like to `react-native-navigation` docs. please go through and do post your code so that others can help you.